# Proving equation at zero?

Tags: trigonometry

I have an equation
$$x = \csc(\theta) - \cot(\theta).$$

As $\theta$ approaches zero, $x$ approaches zero.  However, trying to solve the equation at zero yields an undefined result.

How do I rewrite the equation to be continuous at 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  Write the cosecant and cotangent in terms of sine and cosine.  You can then combine the two fractions to give an expression that goes to 0/0.  Expanding in a Taylor series or L'Hopital's rule will then be your friend.

Comment: Instead of Taylor series or l'Hôpital's rule, one can use the fact that $1 - \cos\theta = 2\sin^2(\theta/2)$, and then expand $\sin\theta$ in terms of $\theta/2$ as well.

Comment: Indeed, you can only treat this properly in terms of limits.

Comment: @Rahul Narain ah! thats it.  So rewriting and canceling gives me $\tan(\theta/2)$!